# Scala combinator parsers: repetition and subsequent concatenated rules subsets of rule in repetition

Tags: scala

I am parsing strings using scala combinators, I would like strings such as
"Ph" or "Ph." or "Ph. D" or "Ph.D." to be successfully parsed, among those, for the moment the three first one are successfully parsed, but when I execute `println(parseAll(name, "Ph.D."))`, I see the following:

```
[1.6] failure: string matching regex `\p{IsLatin}+' expected but end of source found

Ph.D.
     ^
```

My intuition is that because `nameSepSubset` is a rule used by `nameSep`, `rep1(nameSub ~ nameSep)` consumes everything in "Ph.D." and thus yields no input to `nameSub ~ nameSepSubset`.
Is there another operator than `rep1` or another way of defining my grammar that would solve this problem?

The grammar:

```
lazy val nameSub = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r
lazy val nameSepSubset = (
    rep1(" ")
    ||| "." ~ rep1(" ")
    ||| ".")

lazy val nameSep = (
        nameSepSubset
        ||| rep(" ") ~ "," ~ rep(" ")
        ||| rep(" ") ~> "-" <~ rep(" ")
        ||| "'")


lazy val name = (rep1(nameSub ~ nameSep) ~ nameSub ~ nameSepSubset
                 ||| nameSub ~ nameSepSubset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to redefine the rules for name, using a recursive definition of name:

```
lazy val name = nameSub ~ nameSep ~ name //(1)
                ||| nameSub ~ nameSepSubset /*(2)*/ ||| "" /*(3)*/
```

you can see that legal outputs would be:

`nameSub ~ nameSepSubset` from rule (2) which is equivalent to
`nameSub ~ nameSepSubset ~ ""` that can be derived from rule (3)

or

```
nameSub ~ nameSep ~ nameSub ~ nameSepSub
```

or

```
nameSub ~ nameSep ~ nameSub ~ nameSep ~ nameSub ~ nameSepSub
```

or

...